# Empty string returned while trying to retrieve the text contents of an element of QListView

Tags: qt, pyqt5, squish

I am trying to automate a PyQt based application that uses a QListView in icon mode using Squish
Inorder to select a specific item in the view, i need to first identify the text of the item. I am using the below code to do the same

```
targetList = waitForObject("{name='someListView' type='QListView'}")

object.children(targetList)[11].model().data(object.children(targetList)[11]).toString()
```

Here object.children(targetList)[11] is of type QModelIndex

But the above code always returns an empty string.

Is there any other way to retrieve the text data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use `QListView` API only. So, in case of valid `targetList` object, i.e. it's found by `waitForObject` function, I would write:

```
targetList = waitForObject("{name='someListView' type='QListView'}")

model = targetList.model()
col = targetList.modelColumn
idx = model.index(11, col)
itemString = idx.data().toString()
```

Comment: Did you notice my edit? It should be `model.index(11, col)` and not `model.index(col, 11)`.

Comment: yes i did. But it still return empty string. but still thanks for a much neater way to retrieve the index

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
def main():
    # Use itemviews example included in Squish:
    startApplication("itemviews")

    # Configure QListView to use IconMode as
    # mentioned by original poster:
    obj = waitForObject("{occurrence='2' type='QListView' unnamed='1' visible='1'}")
    obj.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)

    # Get desired item via object.children();
    # this yields a "wrapped" QModelIndex which
    # features a property "text" which contains
    # the desired text:
    it = object.children(obj)[4]

    test.log("item text: %s" % it.text)
```